# Partitioned matrices back to array

Tags: list-manipulation

```
mat1 = Table[
   If[i > j, RandomReal[], -RandomReal[]], {i, 16}, {j, 16}];

mat2 = Partition[mat1, {4,4}];
```

Is there a possibility to get the first one from the second one. I have a form as in mat2 ie, as partitioned matrices. Can I get the form as in mat1 ie, 16 X 16? When I use flatten, the issue is like it's changing the place of terms.

Comment: this is tricky but: `Flatten[mat2, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]`

Comment: Great, thanks. So far I have been doing {1,2},{3,4} !!!

Comment: i had to play around to figure that out (I sure didn't get it first try) but i should have checked the details in the docs!  they say: "If the `m[i,j]` are matrices, `Flatten[{{m[1,1], m[2,2]},{m[2,1],m[2,2]}},{{1,3},{2,4}}]` effectively constructs a single matrix from the "blocks" `m[i,j]`. "

Comment: @thorimur `Flatten[mat2, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]` is the same as `ArrayFlatten[mat2]`, see [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html#84678301).

Comment: @Roman ah, thanks! i feel like this equivalence should be mentioned in the details section of `Flatten`'s docs alongside the above quote.